# Angularjs changing class name on url change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to add 'active' class to my menu items on url change.

This is what I've tried so far : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Taxellool/uwy45ry4/5/)

(p.s: I tried to use stack's code snippets but it doesn't seem to work)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="townApp">
  <aside ng-controller="sideCtrl">
    <ul id="sidebar">
      <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-class="{'active': item.link == url}">
        <a href="{{ item.link }}" ng-click="activate(item);">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{ item.icon }}"></i>
        {{ item.text | uppercase }}
        </a>            
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var townApp = angular.module('townApp', []);

townApp.controller('sideCtrl', function($scope, $location){
  $scope.menuItems = [
    {text:"dashboard", link:"#/dashboard", icon:"tint"}, 
    {text:"payments", link:"#/payments", icon:"tint"}, 
    {text:"graphs", link:"#/graphs", icon:"tint"},
  ];
  $scope.url = '#' + $location.absUrl().split('/#')[1];
  $scope.activate = function(item){
    $scope.url = '#' + $location.absUrl().split('/#')[1];
  }
});
```

This is working good on my local machine's page load.(not on jsfiddle which seems reasonable) but the problem is when clicking on each menu item, 'active' class will be added to previous clicked item.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish here, could you give a little more detail?

Comment: I'm trying to apply 'active' class on the menu item which has the link attribute that equals the current partial of url which comes after '#'. 
so that on clicking on an outside link like http://domain.com/#/payments, the menu Item which leads to '#/payments' becomes active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwy45ry4/6/)**. The important change happened on these lines:

```
$scope.activate = function(item){
    $scope.url = item.link;
}
```

Basically, the `activate` function is triggered before the URL is changed, that is why it was taking the URL of the previous item.

An **alternate solution** would be to use `$timeout` **([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwy45ry4/7/))**:

```
$scope.activate = function(item){
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.url = '#' + $location.absUrl().split('/#')[1];
  });
}
```

(Do not forget to inject `$timeout` into your controller in such case.)

Comment: Works great. Thanks.

Comment: @Taxellool, you are welcome, please mark the answer as correct if it helped, so it may serve future visitors as well. Thanks.

Comment: sure dude. was waiting for 15 minutes time limit

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the item that you're passing in as the url hasn't changed yet:

```
    $scope.url = '#' + $location.absUrl().split('/#')[1];

    $scope.activate = function(item){
        $scope.url = item.link;
    }
```